# Android service constantly running and polling

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager, polling

I've to implement a simple application for test purpose with an always running service in background that polls a server every few seconds.
I'm aware of GCM but in my case it is impossible to use as I'm in an intranet without Internet connection.

So I need some explanation on which are the best practices: how can I implement the service to do something every few seconds? AlarmManager? Handler?

Thanks!

Comment: Use a Handler if there is an active looper thread to which you can post the timer request.   Use the Alarm manager if you need to wake up your application if it's not running.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one method of doing something repeatedly:

```
private ScheduledExecutorService exec;

private void startExec() {
    shutDownExec();
    exec = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    exec.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // starts immediately and is run once every minute
        }
    }, 0, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
}

private void shutDownExec() {
    if (exec != null && !exec.isTerminated()) {
        exec.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Can of course be wrapped in a Service to make it run as long as the service lives.

Comment: Which are the differences between your solution and calling sleep method in a thread?

Comment: It is independent of the time it takes to run the task: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513518/how-does-the-method-scheduledexecutorservice-scheduleatfixedrate-ensures-real Otherwise not so much I guess. Besides the fact that I find it easier to maintain and read.